# How to access Backbone Fetch data server side

Tags: javascript, python, backbone.js, flask

I have a backbone model that I am calling fetch with. I have a flask server on which i need to access the id of the backbone model. I cannot seem to get my hands on the id of the model on the server. How can I access the `entityId` in my flask code

```
BB.Politician = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        type: "Politician"
    },
    url: "/my_url_here"
});
var currentUser = new BB.Politician({"entityId": "1625"});
currentUser.fetch({
    //method: "POST",
    success: function(user){
        currentUserView.render();
    }
});

#Flask server code
@app.route('/my_url_here', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def return_poitician():
    print request
    print request.args
    print request.values 

    #none of the above print statements are giving me the "entityId"
    return data
```

I also tried adding in the id in the route but that just threw a 404 error when the `fetch()` executed:

```
@app.route('/my_url_here/<entityId>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def return_poitician(entityId):
    print entityId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@app.route('/my_url_here/<entityId>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

isn't picking up any `id` because you aren't sending any.

Backbone fetch uses the `id` field of the model to construct the fetch URL, in your case I would recommend turning the `entityId` into `id`:

```
BB.Politician = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        type: "Politician"
    },
    url: "/my_url_here"
});
var currentUser = new BB.Politician({"id": "1625"});
```

and let Backbone construct the GET, which would look like:

```
"/my_url_here/" + this.get('id'); // this refers to model
```

which turns into

```
"/my_url_here/1625"
```

`Backbone.Model.url` also accepts function as value so you can define your own logic for constructing URLs. For instance, if you must retain the `entityId` you can construct your `url` like:

```
url: function () {
    return "/my_url_here" + this.get('entityId');
}
```

Comment: Its a strange thing. I tried switching the `entityId` to simply `id` but it wasnt registering/appending the id onto the url. I was under the impression that this was how it worked with models, that it queried the url with the model attached. I dont know why its not registering on my app. However switching it to the function as in the second part of your answer worked. Thanks.

Comment: If your Model exists without a collection then you should use `urlRoot` instead of `url`, see here: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url

Comment: That would explain it. Thanks for all the help. Methinks I need to start re-reading the docs.